# Consume RTSP Stream In HTML

Tags: html, html5-video, axis, rtsp

I am trying To Consume RTSP Stream in HTML using VLC Web Plugin.
Getting An error vlc.playlist.playItem(id) Undefined.
Is there any way to consume RTSP in HTML?

Comment: please post some code

Comment: You might want to share an example RTSP stream URL also - the error may be in the stream itself.